# Symlink existing directory

Tags: bash, unix, symlink, ln

I have an app in `/usr/abc` and I want to link the `abc` app to `/dump/abc` (this is an existing directory).
When I run `ln -s /usr/abc /dump/abc` the link is created inside `/dump/abc/abc` directory. But I need the content of `/usr/abc` to be in `/dump/abc` and not in `/dump/abc/abc`.

When I do `ls -l /dump/abc`, I get

```
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 15 Dec 11:00 abc -> /usr/abc
```

The desired result when I do `ls -l /dump/abc` is the content of `/usr/abc`.

Can someone help me here?

Comment: If `/dump/abc` is empty, you can just delete this directory, then rerun `ln -s /usr/abc /dump/abc`.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, But i am not supposed to delete the directory but create symlink to existing directory.

Comment: Actually you don't really have the choice: on *nix OSes, directories are files, and symlinks are files as well. You can either have a directory or a symlink in the same path, but not both of them of course

Answer (score 1):

if your intention is to preserve existing /dump/abc you can bind-mount /usr/abc. when done umount /dump/abc to restore the previous state

```
mount -o bind /usr/abc /dump/abc
```

Comment: it's not a symlink